# Android button background selector

Tags: android, button, selector

I want to use the following selector for button:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/jobs" android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
<scale android:scaleHeight="90%" android:scaleWidth="90%" />
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/jobs"></item>

</selector>
```

But it does not work. 
I want to make buttons corners round and 10% small in size with the same drawable. Actually I want to give a button pressed effect using single drawable. Is it possible?

Answer (score 21):

I find it best to separate the state logic and drawable code.  From the Android docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_hovered="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- hovered -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

I would then put the code to give rounded corners in a separate drawable XML.  I'm not sure if you can even do such things directly in a `selector`.