# Android : When Button Down Change Pic Consecutive

Tags: android

i Want to change picture Consecutive when button is down on android 4.2
this code is only change one time

code:

```
public void addListenerOnButton() {


    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);

    i = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);

    b1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        while (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                 ii++;
                    if (ii%2==1) i.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic1); else i.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic2);

                    return true;

        }

                return false;

        }

    });

}
```

Comment: ACTION_DOWN will only trigger a single time when the finger is initially pushed down onto the screen. Holding the finger there does not invoke more ACTION_DOWNs. You should be setting a flag to say 'the user's finger is down' when you get ACTION_DOWN and turn off the flag when you get ACTION_UP. Then, you can use another thread to change the images whilst the flag is on. You could scrap the thread and use an animation instead, as vmironov's answer describes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the code bellow. It should produce the result that you want

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    final AnimationDrawable animation = new AnimationDrawable();

    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pic1), 200);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pic2), 200);
    animation.setOneShot(false);

    image.setImageDrawable(animation);
    button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                animation.start();
                button.setPressed(true);
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                animation.stop();
                button.setPressed(false);
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't really think that this is overkill. Without an `animation` you have to manually change the button resource every XXX milliseconds, use `Handler.postDelayed` or something, to manually stop it and so on. `AnimationDrawable` takes care about all this stuff and allows you to simplify the code.

Comment: @WarrenFaith, here you can find the first version of the answer http://pastebin.com/k2hdYCsi. It doesn't use an animation, but it has much more code, harder to understand and easier to make a mistake. So i decided to use an `AnimationDrawable` instead.

Comment: I not even get why the background should be changed programmatically. The layout should give the button a selector as background and in this selector you define a pressed state and a normal state each with the resource you want. Result is: you don't need an `OnTouchListener` and you don't need to care about image changing. An example for a selector: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11866804/180538

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible to achive the same result using selector only. Ok, you can provide an `AnimationDrawable` for a `state_pressed` but how are you going to save the current frame when view isn't pressed anymore?

Comment: Also, it is needed to change `ImageView`'s background when `Button` is pressed. So `ImageView`'s state is actually not even changing.

Answer (score 0):

store your images in a int array like this

```
int imgarr[]={R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img2,R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img3};
take an int to maintain count
int mCount=0;


now onClick()
{

img.setImageResource(imgarr[mCount]);

if(mCount<imgarr.length)
mCount++;

else
mCount=0;

}
```

Comment: That's not what he's asking

Comment: Well I think this is what he is asking for, he will let us know in case he wants something different and we can help him then too

Comment: The question and the code clearly show the he wants to *continuously* change image

Comment: i want use setOnTouchListener

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
while (true){

    if(event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        break
    }
    ii++;
       if (ii%2==1) i.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic1); else i.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic2);

       return true;

}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this cause an ANR?

Comment: @miniBill It wouldn't ANR because the while loop is completely ignored (one control path breaks, the other returns out of the loop).