# Android ImageButton push color

Tags: android, imagebutton

I have an ImageButton that I switch the images when pushed. The problem is that the animation tints the button blue when I push the button between my two image switches. How to I prevent that blueish tint from animating? Also, how do you do it programatically and not through the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Well for most use cases, you should be using XML... but lecture aside, the blue background is part of a [`StateListDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) that is set by default as your button's background.  Defining and setting your own background (via [`setBackgroundResource(int resId)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29) or similar) should be sufficient to "get rid" of the focused color state.

Comment: The buttons are dynamically created for a matching game where the user specifies the number of buttons at run time.

Comment: @Matthew perfectly valid use case - I only mention it because I see a fair number of beginner android folk try to do everything through code for no good reason

Comment: Well, you guessed it because I am not a beginner, but am still a "noob" :) so I make silly mistakes all the time. That said, how do you use the StateListDrawable? I saw there is a pressed attribute. Do I attach a new StateListDrawable object to the ImageButton somehow?

Comment: Well you don't have to use a StateListDrawable - any drawable will do, but the default is one.  If you would like to set up the tint to be a different color so it doesn't conflict with your images I refer you to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866623/android-button-background-selector .  Just define an XML file in /res/drawable and set the background of your button to be that XML resource - Magic then ensues :)